How to enable to select culture with both url and cookie in asp.net core razor and blazor pages?
I have applied Localization in my asp.net core mvc project.
It includes blazor pages for Identity.
I want to enable to change the culture by changing the site url's culture part.
domain/en/Home/Index
Currently, the culture can be changed by cookie.
This is the cookie culture switch
But when I change the url's culture to ja, the culture isn't changing.
How to enable both without any restriction each other?
I added the following code to add culture to the url, but it didn't work for Blazor pages.
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{culture}/{controller=First}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

I want to apply this to Blazor pages to.
And I added the partial for the culture switch.
<div>
    <form asp-action="CultureManagement" asp-controller="Home" method="post" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">
        <select name="cultureName" asp-for="@culture!.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" asp-items="@cultureList"
            onchange="this.form.submit();">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

It only changes the cookie.
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CultureManagement(string cultureName, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(cultureName)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(30) });
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}

I want to enable to change culture by changing the url and cookie.
And also want to apply to blazor pages.

Change your CultureManagement method like below.
And make sure your returnUrl is correct when switch to other pages.
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CultureManagement(string cultureName, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(cultureName)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(30) }
        );


        var uri = new Uri(string.Concat(Request.Scheme, "://", Request.Host, returnUrl));
        var pathAndQuery = uri.PathAndQuery;

        var newPathAndQuery = Regex.Replace(pathAndQuery, "^/[^/]+", $"/{cultureName}");

        return Redirect(newPathAndQuery);
    }




Thank you for your response.
It works very well.
But I still have problem with exceptional pages.
I'm using Identity and it's consisted of Blazor pages.
They don't work on the mvc pattern set on the program.cs file.
https://localhost:44370/Identity/Account/Manage
How can I change to these blazor pages to include the culture?
Thanks always.

Hi @maxray Here is a good blog you can refer ADDING LOCALIZATION TO THE ASP.NET CORE IDENTITY PAGES

@maxray Waiting for your updates, have a nice day.

Thank you for your help @jason-pan.
You were very helpful for my work.
And for other users, I'm going to post the most suitable code snippet for Blazor page url localization.
Please add the following code to program.cs - it worked very well for me.
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Identity", "/Account/", model =>
         {
             model.Selectors.ForEach(x =>
             {
                 if (x.AttributeRouteModel.Template.StartsWith("Identity"))
                 {
                     x.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
                     {
                         Order = -1,
                         Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(("{culture=en-US}"),
                             x.AttributeRouteModel.Template)
                     };
                 }
             });


         });
    });

I found this code from the following discussion.
Routed localization in identity pages in ASP.NET Core MVC
Thanks to our community.
